# c# handle null byte array from mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, byte, blob

i have created an app that basically looks for blob records on a mysql server problem i have is that if for whatever reason the blob field is empty the app crashes. I thought on something like

i currently have

```
byte[] data = (byte[])DbReader[2];
```

but i was wondering if there is any way to do something like

```
if (DbReader.IsDbNull(2)
    byte[] data = /* DEFAULT VALUE */
else
    byte[] data = (byte[])DbReader[2];
```

but can i set a default value?? everything ive tried fails :(

Comment: by default you mean a default value defined in SQL somewhere?

Comment: no just a standard value defined at this stage like 1, 2 or 3 for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
byte[] data = null;
```

Arrays are reference types so you can assign null to them. Later on you will be able see if data is null just like this:

```
if(data != null)
{
    //there is data inside that array, you can go ahead and use it.
}
```

**EDIT: simplification**

You could simplicate your code like this:

```
byte[] data = DbReader.IsDbNull(2) ? null : (byte[])DbReader[2];
```

Comment: implemented a slight variation on this but thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set it as empty array:

```
byte[] data = new byte[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use it in multiple places, you can encapsulate it in an extension method...

```
public static class DbDataReaderExt {
    public static T GetOrDefault<T>(this DbDataReader reader, int index, T default_value = default(T)) {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(index))
            return default_value;
        return (T)reader[index];
    }
}
```

...and then just use it like this...

```
var data = reader.GetOrDefault<byte[]>(2);
```

...or like this:

```
var data = reader.GetOrDefault(2, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

BTW, this should work for non-`byte[]` types as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx) method:

```
object value = DbReader[2];
byte[] data = ... some default value
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(value))
{
    data = (byte[])value;
}
```